# Python sqlalchemy Attribute Error while creating engine

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I have Python 3.6, pymysql 0.7.11 and sqlalchemy 1.2.4

I am having an issue creating an engine with sqlalchemy.

When I try (credentials changed for privacy, except for ":3306" as the port and the encd variable):

```
import pymysql
import sqlalchemy  

login = ‘username’
passwd = ‘password’
server = '1.1.1.1:3306'
db = 'db_name'
encd = 'charset=utf8'

engine_str = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}?{}'.format(login, passwd, server, db, encd)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_str)
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes' has no attribute 'NativeForEmulated'
```

Note that I also tried without the port :3306 and had same error.

The error occurs at this point, not when connecting the engine or using the connection.

When I create an engine with mypysql using the same credentials, it works fine:

```
engine = pymysql.connect(user=login, password=passwd,
                                   host='1.1.1.1',
                                   database=db, port=‘3306’)
```

but I need sqlalchemy for this project.

I haven't found anything searching for this error message. I tried running the exact same code on a different computer and it worked fine. Does anyone have any insight?